# segmentation fault (core dumped) error when using time function

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

Hello i am new to Linux and c programming so this might be stupid question but i couldn't find an answer.

I am writing a home work and they want me to print the execution time at the end of program using `time()` function, so when i used the function in my program i got the message `segmentation fault (core dumped)` and when i remove it the program works agine.
Then i created a test file in the code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    time();
    return 0;
}
```

And i got the same error message.

Also tried :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    time(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

And

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t;

    time(&t);
    return 0;
}
```

And got the same error.

so what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: works for me. How are you compiling it? Are you sure you are running the right program?

Comment: The first program won't compile because you're missing the argument.

Comment: All the above programs compile for me and the problem in the execution

Comment: i am compiling in terminal using gcc "c file" -o "output file"

Comment: @TheMask strictly saying, it will compile due to lacking to include <time.h>, unless `-Wall -Werror` or analogs are used to make warnings fatal. But this doesn't mean the program becomes correct;)

Comment: @Netch: You're right. I forget that.

Comment: It worked, i am so sorry my fault 
Thanks for the fast replays guys 
should i delete the question or just accept an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first two examples, you forget to include time.h.  That is the cause of the segmentation fault in those examples.  If you're using gcc, try compiling with -Wall (which turns on all warnings).  You should get a warning indicating an implicit declaration of function "time" - in other words, that you've forgotten to include time.h.

Your final example, however, works fine for me.  If you keep getting a segmentation fault, however, try debugging with gdb.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  time_t now;
  time(&now);

  printf("%s", ctime(&now));

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```